# Jenkins: Trigger another job with branch name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using Jenkins Pipeline via declarative and I would like to trigger another job with branch name.

For instance, I have two different pipeline(PipelineA -PipelineB) with stages `JobA` and `JobB`.

One of the stage for `JobA` should trigger the `JobB` via paramater using `env.GIT_BRANCH`. What I mean, if we trigger the `JobA` via origin/develop, then it should trigger the 'JobB' and run the stages where it has origin/develop condition.

Meanwhile, we also making some separate changes on `JobB` and it also has its own GIT_BRANCH expression.Thus I could not able to find a way to manage this separately without affecting `JobA`. To be clarify, when JobA trigger JobB with origin/stage parameter, due to latest changes on JobB is origin/development whereas GIT_BRANCH is origin/development, I can not able to run the stages which has stage condition.

Here is my script.

```
    stage ('Job A') {
        steps {
            script {
                echo "Triggering job for branch ${env.GIT_BRANCH}"
                ret = build(job: "selenium_tests", 
                                parameters: [
                                    string(name: "projectName", value: "Project1"),
                                    string(name: "branchName", value: "env.GIT_BRANCH")
                                ],
                                propagate: true,
                                wait: true)

                echo ret.result
                currentBuild.result = ret.result
            }           
        }
    }
```

---

```
parameters {    
    string(defaultValue: "project1", description: 'Which project do you want to test?', name: 'projectName')
    string(defaultValue: "origin/development", description: 'Environment for selenium tests', name:'branchName')
}


    stage ('Job B') {
        when {
            beforeAgent true
            expression { params.projectName == 'Project1' }
            expression { params.branchName == "origin/stage"}
            expression{ return env.GIT_BRANCH == "origin/stage"}
        }
        steps {
            script {
                  //Do something
            }           
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want Job B run against code from desired branch, just add one stage to switch to desired branch, and no condition is necessary on each stage of Job B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass down one more param for branch when trigger Job B

```
stage('Trigger Job A') {}

stage('Trigger Job B') {
    when {
       allOf {
         beforeAgent true
         expression { params.projectName == 'Project1' }
         expression{ return env.GIT_BRANCH == "origin/stage"}
       }
    }
    steps {
    build(job: "selenium_tests/Job B", 
      parameters: [
          string(name: "projectName", value: "Project1")
          strint(name: "branchName", value: "${env.GIT_BRANCH}")
      ],
      propagate: true,
      wait: true)       
    }
}
```

In Job B' Jenkinsfile add one stage as the first stage to switch to desired branch

```
pipeline {
    
    parameters {
        string(name: 'branchName', defaultValue: 'develop')
    }

    stages {

        stage('Switch branch') {
            steps {
                sh "git checkout ${params.branchName}"
            }
        }
        // other stages

    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with adding my current when expression for stage. The issue is, we made also some changes on JobB cause it is seperate pipeline. Thus let assume the branchname that we trigger from JobA is stage but due to latest GIT_BRANCH is development for JobB then none of stage is running for Job B

Comment: Your updated description make me more confusion.  Please simplify your requirement.  From my understanding,  Two jobs, Job A and Job B,  If there are code commit pushed to any branch of repo for Job A,   Job A will call Job B,  and  I hope the Job B running against  the code from desired branch.   Is this your requirement?

Comment: For example, I have repo A to hold my app source code, another repo B to hold my test code,  once i commit app code change to develop branch, i hope to run the test code  on develop branch of repo B.

Comment: Yes you are correct.. But repo B also hold our test code and it has three branches such as develop,stage and master.. Meanwhile we also make some changes on repo B where Job B is running. So the last change on JoB is development. But Job A changes on stage branch. So as shown in my question ı have two expressions where first check GIT_BRANCH where the other check params.branchName comes from Job A. that is why due to these are different none of stages are running

Comment: if you need all conditions meet, you should use `allOf` https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when-example